# std::iterator и пользовательский итератор

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

1. Почему не получается так сделать? Ведь `vector<int> :: iterator` в моём понимании унаследован от `random_access_iterator`.

   `vector<int> vec({5, 4, 2, 3, 1});`

   `vector<int> :: iterator it = vec.begin()`

   `const iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, int>& i = it;`
2. Нужно сделать, чтобы метод класса контейнера принимал и `std::iterator` и `MyIterator`, который уже написан мной. Думал, что можно было бы базовый класс.
3. Как можно решить проблему пункта 2.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, итератор вектора не наследуется от `random_access_iterator`. Итератор вектора - отдельная структура в которой просто прописан его тэг следующим образом:

```
using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
```

Вашу проблему можно решить следующим образом (используется стандарт C++20)

```
#include <iterator>
//...
template <std::random_access_iterator Iter>
return_type method_name(const Iter& iter, ...) {
    //...
}
```

Тогда ваш метод сможет принимать все итераторы, являющиеся random access.